# Telerik MVC Grid Rebind Crashes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, telerik, telerik-grid

Following the patten as set out in the Telerik Mvc Grid Demo for inserting and editing, everything works up until it gets to the point where the controller method returns.

See: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/Grid/EditingAjax?theme=vista

The methods call into my repository functions which successfully update the database; however, the return code in the demo as shown here

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]        
[CultureAwareAction]        
[GridAction]        
public ActionResult _InsertAjaxEditing()
{
    EditableProduct product = new EditableProduct();            
    if (TryUpdateModel(product)) {
        SessionProductRepository.Insert(product);
    }            
    return View(new GridModel(SessionProductRepository.All()));        
}
```

Everything works up to the return line, so I tried:

1. return View(new GridModel(myTypeRepository.All);
2. return View(new GridModel(myTypeRepository.All.ToList());
3. return View(new GridModel(myTypeRepository.All.ToArray());
4. return View(new GridModel(myTypeRepository.All);
5. return View(new GridModel(myTypeRepository.All.ToList());
6. return View(new GridModel(myTypeRepository.All.ToArray());
7. return View(GridModel(myTypeRepository.All))
8. return View(GridModel(myTypeRepository.All.ToList()))
9. return View(GridModel(myTypeRepository.All.ToArray()))

All of which resulted in an exception that could not be followed because it points to the Telerik file: GridActionAttribute.cs.

Now because it occurs at the end of the method, I can't be sure that it is the return statment or the html.Telerik.Grid. However, as I said I followed the pattern in the demo:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<BerettaFarms.Models.FoodKind>()
    .Name("myName")
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.myTypeId))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => {
        dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("SelectAjaxEditing", "myController")
            .Insert("InsertAjaxEditing", "myController")
            .Update("SaveAjaxEditing", "myController")
            .Delete("DeleteAjaxEditing", "myController");
    })       
    .Columns(columns => {            
        columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(200);            
        columns.Bound(o => o.Description).Width(400);
        columns.Command(commands => {
            commands.Edit();
            commands.Delete();
        }).Width(200);  
    })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("AjaxIndex", "myController"))
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))               
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(h => h.Height("700px"))       
    .Groupable()        
    .Filterable()
)
```

So if anyone knows why the rebind fails? Or if it is attributable to something else, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

AS it turns out this is one of those issues related to the tools and not the substance. When you remove all the breakpoints in this method and just let the code run it works as expected. Somehow, when in debugging mode, with breakpoints set, it throws an error an halts the application.